# push-notification is not receiving in iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification

I am a php developer. I am implementing a push notification module for iPhone. For that I am using php for server side implementation. Though I am getting "Connected to APNS {"aps":{"alert":"HI Push","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}Message successfully delivered" message, iPhone does not receive any notification. My php code is like:

```
<? php
  include('include/connect.php');
  $device = mysql_query("SELECT device_token,badge,alert,sound FROM push_notification WHERE device_status='1' ");
  while($res = mysql_fetch_array($device)){
     // Put your device token here (without spaces):
     $deviceToken = $res['device_token'];
     // Put your private key's passphrase here:
     $passphrase = "pushchat";
     // Put your alert message here:
     //$message = trim($_REQUEST['alert']);
     $message = "HI Push" ;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     $ctx = stream_context_create();
     stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
     stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
     // Open a connection to the APNS server
     $fp = stream_socket_client(
       'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);            
    if (!$fp)
      exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);            echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;         
         $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,'badge' => 1,'sound' => 'default');       // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    echo $payload;
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
       echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
       echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
       fclose($fp); 
}
```

?>

objective c code is like:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Register for Push Notification Type    

    deviceTokenString=[[NSString alloc]init];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) ];

    /*---------------Increasing Badge No-----------*/

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;


}

#pragma mark-
#pragma mark PushNotification Delegate methods
/*------ Provide a user explanation for a place to get Device Token-------*/
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    /*---------Get The Device Token here--------------*/




    deviceTokenString = [deviceToken description];
    deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];






}



    /*------ Provide a user explanation for when the registration fails-------*/
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error 
{

    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", error); 

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSLog(@"Received Notification");

    NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);

    NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);

    NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];


}
```

Comment: Do you have the correct combination of certificates - sandbox server using test certificate and developer certificate to build the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether the certificates matching. For ex. If the iphone is in debug mode the server also use developer certificate for push notification and if the iPhone is build in the distribution, then the server use the production certificate for sending push notification. Please verify your certificates are matching. Also check the iPhone settings whether the notification is enabled for your app or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it is working fine with the developer certificate.

Comment: But in production certificate, I could not able to get device token. Is there any need to change in our server? Please help me.

Comment: while using production certificate, you cant use sandbox to send push notification. Have to use the direct apns server url for sending push notification.

Comment: like `$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);`

Comment: I'm sorry that i didn't notice that you don't able to get the device token. For that please try deleting the existing distribution certificate from your system. Download it freshly from your developer account of apple and try building with that certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. It works perfect.         application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0; application.     applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];  I use thse above two lines to increase the badge count.But unfortunately it is not incrementing, it is showing only one constant value that is 1. Is there any need to change in the server part? Please help me.

Comment: The above code will set the value you passed from server as `badge` along with the notification payload as the application badge number. If it seems that only displaying 1, then it means that all the time when you are getting the badge as 1 from the server. From the server side, we are deciding how much unread notification your app had. right?

Comment: Please try to send the correct value according to your application's notification logic from the server to the app.